# How to add arrays without the final array saying 'array'?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, append

I am appending multidimensional arrays with a for-loop in the way described below. However, the output is not as desired. The desired output is one array consisting of multiple 5D arrays.

```
import numpy as np

series_1 = [
             [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
             [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
             [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

series_2 = [
         [0.  1.  0.  0.  0. ],
         [0.  0.5 0.5 0.  0. ],
         [0.  1.  0.  0.  0. ],
         [0.  0.  1.  0.  0. ]]

series_3 = [
         [1.  0.  0.  0.  0. ],
         [0.5 0.  0.  0.  0. ],
         [1.  0.  0.  0.  0. ],
         [1.  0.  0.  0.  0. ],
         [0.  0.  0.  1.  0. ]]

phases = [1, 2, 3]
average_total = []
for phase in phases:
    if phase == 1:
        average_series_T = series_1
    elif phase == 2:
        average_series_T = series_2
    elif phase == 3:
        average_series_T = series_3

    # add each phase to the total sequence
    average_total.append(average_series_T)


print("average total:")
print(average_total)
```

Output:

```
[array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]), array([[0. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 0.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 1. , 0. , 0. ]]), array([[1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 1. , 0. ]])]
```

However, I want the output to be:

```
    [
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], 
    [0. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
    [0. , 0.5, 0.5, 0. , 0. ],
    [0. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
    [0. , 0. , 1. , 0. , 0. ], 
    [1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
    [0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
    [1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
    [1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
    [0. , 0. , 0. , 1. , 0. ],
]
```

I would like the output to be an array of 5D arrays, however a Pandas DataFrame or something alike would also work. I basically want to put together the series_1 series_2 and series_3 into one object with the shape (x,5), where x is the number of 5D arrays.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the whole code and using the right indentation please?

Comment: I fixed it! Hope it is easier to follow now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Series are not comma separated, is this your real code? Are you using any lib?

Comment: Sorry for that. Fixed it, also the lib.

Comment: Add numpy as a tag since it is very different from normal python

Comment: The inner arrays in series does not includes commas neither. Try to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
L_arrays=[serie_1]
L_arrays.append(serie_2)
L_arrays.append(serie_3)

result = []
for i in range(len(L_arrays)):
    for row in L_arrays[i]:
        result.append(row)

print(array(result))
```

Comment: yes this helped, thank you! A minor change is that I put `print(np.array(result)` instead of `print(array(result))`, but with that change it lead to the desired output.

Comment: Yes I forgot you used `import numpy as np` and not `from numpy import *`. 
I'm glad to help you. If my answer satisfies you, you can click on 'accept the answer' so the other users will find the answer quickly.